# Insert new values inside primary key column based on existing ones keeping the unicity constraint and maximum length constraint

Tags: java, sql, oracle

This problem can be either solved in Java or using Oracle SQL. The problem is stated as:
Given a table with a primary key column (pkCol) and some other columns (here only colA), for example:

```
pkCol colA
----  ----
a      2
b      2
c      3
```

I would like to insert new values in this table to have something similar to:

```
pkCol colA
----  ----
a      2 
b      2
c      3
a_1    2
b_1    2
c_1    3
```

The new primary key values should look somehow like the original values they copied while the other columns should be kept as they were.
The constraints for the new values are:
1. the new value to be inserted has to be unique across pkCol
2. the new value has to have a maximum length allowed by the 'pkCol' limit
 (given by the table structure).

I tried to emulate this problem in Java, create a HashSet with the pkCol values and then create a HashMap having the key the old value from pkCOl and actual value for the map, the new computed pkCol. The method to get the new value does this: if it has length left to append new characters it tries first to append '0' if the resulted value is not unique, then it tries with '1' then with '2' then... with '01' and so on (a brute force algorithm for all the possible string combinations is on the 'else' branch). If it does not have enough space to append a value then it will simply replace on character with another one until it find a unique new value.

java

```
int keysSize = 5000000;
Random rand = new Random();

HashSet<String> keys = Sets.newHashSet();
for(int i = 0; i < keysSize; i++){
    keys.add(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(1 + rand.nextInt(100)));
}
System.out.println("a");

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
Map<String, String> pkTransition = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(keysSize);
System.out.println("b");
for(String key : keys){
  String newValue = generateNextString(keys, key, 100);
  assertTrue(!newValue.isEmpty());
  pkTransition.put(key, newValue);
}

long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(totalTime/1000000);


private String generateNextString(
  HashSet<String> usedValues, String currentValue, int maxSize){

  char[] possibleNewCharacters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
  int currentValueLength = currentValue.length();
  int lengthLeft = maxSize - currentValueLength;

  char[] result = new char[possibleNewCharacters.length];
  int[] index = new int[possibleNewCharacters.length];

  Arrays.fill(result, 0, result.length, possibleNewCharacters[0]);  
  Arrays.fill(index,  0, index.length, 0);


  if(lengthLeft == 0){
    for(int currentLength = 1; currentLength < maxSize; currentLength++){
    for( int length = 1; length <= possibleNewCharacters.length; length++ ) {
        StringBuilder computedValue = new StringBuilder(currentValue);
                    computedValue.setCharAt(currentLength, possibleNewCharacters[length]);


                if(!usedValues.contains(computedValue.toString())){
            return computedValue.toString();
        }
    }
    }
 }else{
    for( int length = 1; length <= possibleNewCharacters.length && length < lengthLeft; length++ ) {
        int updateIndex = 0;
        do {
                String newValue = currentValue + new String(result, 0, length);
                if(!usedValues.contains(newValue)){
                return newValue;
            }

        for(updateIndex = length-1;
            updateIndex != -1 && ++index[updateIndex] == possibleNewCharacters.length;
            result[updateIndex] = possibleNewCharacters[0], index[updateIndex] = 0, updateIndex--);

        if( updateIndex != -1 ) result[updateIndex] = possibleNewCharacters[index[updateIndex]];
    }
    while(updateIndex != -1);
    }
}

for(int extraTries = 0 ; extraTries < 10; extraTries ++){
    String newValue = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(maxSize);
        if(!usedValues.contains(newValue)){
        return newValue;
    }
}

return "";
}
```

```
Consider this case also

    pkCol colA
    ----  ----
    a      2
    a_1    2
    a_1_1  3

if you try to simply append '_1' you will fail. You need to check for unicitty before.

The problem with the Java approach is that for 5 million records, it works in under 8 seconds. But when I try with 50 million it hangs because it won't have enough space to initialize the HashSet and the HashMap. 

The idea is to be able to work with ~500 million records.

(Edited) For the case with 50 million records, the code will never print System.out.println("a"); 

My machine has 32GB RAM.
```

Comment: You'd have to trade speed: process every row on its own and check whether new generated key exists. You can do that in PL procedure, for example.

Comment: So depending on your NON-key columns value you add a new KEY or a existing KEY_x. Where x is the number of duplicate records you have ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it.

Primary keys (and keys in general) goal is to ensure uniqueness of the rows. They are internal identifiers that are not supposed to be sexy or good looking.

If you want something like this, it means you want to expose it at some point. If you really need it, create a secondary column, with the formatting you want.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't matter if you insert into the same primary column or it is another column. The problem is that I do not know how to do this in Oracle SQL: how to copy the primary keys and alter them a bit considering my constraints. I cannot do this using Java structures.